output stream video produced by ffmpeg gets divided into sections on screen upon streaming
I'm trying to combine cv2 frames with numpy audio array to produce a hls playlist. I'm giving input using pipe. The problem is that while streaming the output hls playlist produced by ffmpeg, the video screen is divided into 4 parts and the sizes of the 4 parts keep getting changed slowly.
Also the audio is extremely distorted.
Attaching images for reference:
at timestamp 00:00
at timestamp 00:03
Here is the script I have written until now:
import cv2
import subprocess
import numpy as np
import librosa

def create_hls_playlist(width, height, frames, audio_data, output_playlist, fps=30, sample_rate=44100):
    print(fps)
    print(height, width)
    print(audio_np.dtype)
    video_args = [
        '-y', 
        "-fflags", "+discardcorrupt",
        '-f', 'rawvideo',
        '-vcodec', 'rawvideo',
        '-s', '{}x{}'.format(width, height),
        '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
        '-r', str(fps),
        '-i', 'pipe:', 
    ]

    audio_args = [
        '-f', 's16le',  
        '-ar', str(sample_rate),  
        '-ac', '1',  
        '-i', 'pipe:', 
    ]


    output_args = [
        "-vf", "scale=1920x1080,setdar=16/9",
        '-an',
        '-c:v', 'libx264',
        '-preset', 'ultrafast',
        '-f', 'hls',
        '-hls_time', '2',
        '-hls_list_size', '0',
        #'-loglevel', 'debug',
        output_playlist,
    ]

    ffmpeg_command = ['ffmpeg'] + video_args + output_args

    ffmpeg_process = subprocess.Popen(ffmpeg_command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

    try:
        for frame in frames[:10]:
            print(f"Frame shape: {frame.shape}, Frame data type: {frame.dtype}")
            # Check for any NaN or infinite values in the frame
            if np.isnan(frame).any() or np.isinf(frame).any():
                print("Frame contains NaN or infinite values!")
            ffmpeg_process.stdin.write(frame.to_string())

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error occurred while writing frames: {e}")
    
    # Write audio data to ffmpeg process
    audio_bytes = audio_data
    ffmpeg_process.stdin.write(audio_bytes)

    for frame in frames[10:]:
      ffmpeg_process.stdin.write(frame)
    
    ffmpeg_process.stdin.flush()

    ffmpeg_process.stdin.close()

    ffmpeg_process.wait()

    ffmpeg_process.stdin.close()


def capture_frames(video_path):
    frames = []
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
    height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        frames.append(frame)

    cap.release()
    return frames, width, height

def load_audio(file_path, duration=None, sr=44100):
    audio_data, _ = librosa.load(file_path, sr=sr, duration=duration)
    print("finished audio-----------------------------------")
    print(audio_data)
    audio_duration = librosa.get_duration(y=audio_data, sr=sr)

    if duration is not None and audio_duration > duration:
        start_sample = 0
        end_sample = int(duration * sr)
        audio_data = audio_data[start_sample:end_sample]
    if np.isnan(audio_data).any() or np.isinf(audio_data).any():
        raise ValueError("Audio data contains NaN or infinite values")

    # Normalize audio data
    # audio_data /= np.max(np.abs(audio_data))
    audio_data = (audio_data * 32767).astype(np.int16)
    print(f"Audio data shape: {audio_data.shape}")
    print(f"Audio data type: {audio_data.dtype}")
    return audio_data

def get_video_frame_rate(video_path):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    if not cap.isOpened():
        raise ValueError(f"Unable to open the video file: {video_path}")

    frame_rate = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    print(frame_rate)
    cap.release()
    return frame_rate

video_path = 'sample.mp4'

output_playlist = 'output.m3u8'
mp3_file_path = 'audio.mp3'
duration = 11  # seconds
sample_rate = 44100  # Hz


if __name__ == "__main__":
    frames, width, height = capture_frames(video_path)
    audio_np = load_audio(mp3_file_path, duration=duration, sr=sample_rate)
    create_hls_playlist(width, height, frames, audio_np, output_playlist)

And the output:
brain@brainywire:~/k/ffmpeg-e$ /bin/python3 /home//ffmpeg-e/stream_f.py
finished audio-----------------------------------
[1.7182100e-06 1.8538897e-06 1.9645518e-06 ... 5.4211184e-02 5.2549735e-02
 5.0875921e-02]
Audio data shape: (485100,)
Audio data type: int16
30
720 1280
int16
Frame shape: (720, 1280, 3), Frame data type: uint8
Error occurred while writing frames: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'to_string'
ffmpeg version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.22.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, rawvideo, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 663552 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[24] / 0x18524742), bgr24, 1280x720, 663552 kb/s, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.0 : mono
Input #1, s16le, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: 705 kb/s
  Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
[libx264 @ 0x5557bf4369c0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x5557bf4369c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x5557bf4369c0] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 4.0, 4:4:4, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x5557bf4369c0] 264 - core 163 r3060 5db6aa6 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=6 threads=18 lookahead_threads=3 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
[s16le @ 0x5557bf3fcf80] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
Output #0, hls, to 'output.m3u8':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264, yuv444p(tv, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 30 fps, 90k tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 aac
[rawvideo @ 0x5557bf3e8640] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
[hls @ 0x5557bf4335c0] Opening 'output0.ts' for writingtrate=N/A speed=5.06x    
[hls @ 0x5557bf4335c0] Opening 'output.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[rawvideo @ 0x5557bf3e8640] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 345), dropping it.
[hls @ 0x5557bf4335c0] Opening 'output1.ts' for writingtrate=N/A speed=5.31x    
[hls @ 0x5557bf4335c0] Opening 'output.m3u8.tmp' for writing
frame=  345 fps=166 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:11.50 bitrate=N/A speed=5.52x    
video:21389kB audio:95kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[libx264 @ 0x5557bf4369c0] frame I:2     Avg QP:21.00  size:666528
[libx264 @ 0x5557bf4369c0] frame P:343   Avg QP:24.78  size: 59968
[libx264 @ 0x5557bf4369c0] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x5557bf4369c0] mb P  I16..4: 22.8%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4: 51.1%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:26.1%
[libx264 @ 0x5557bf4369c0] coded y,u,v intra: 24.0% 3.7% 3.3% inter: 30.6% 4.9% 4.8%
[libx264 @ 0x5557bf4369c0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 43% 38% 10%  9%
[libx264 @ 0x5557bf4369c0] kb/s:15236.21
[aac @ 0x5557bf438400] Qavg: 118.713

I noticed this packet corrupt error and after some digging on stackoverflow found a flag to drop corrupt packets. But that didn't solve the problem.
If I do not drop the corrupted packets, I get this error, if it helps to give any more info:
[rawvideo @ 0x61a72571ab80] PACKET SIZE: 2764800, STRIDE: 3840
[libx264 @ 0x61a725754c40] frame= 323 QP=24.00 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:146 I:2340 P:4474 SKIP:1346 size=62313 bytes
[rawvideo @ 0x61a72571ab80] PACKET SIZE: 2764800, STRIDE: 3840
[libx264 @ 0x61a725754c40] frame= 324 QP=24.00 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:148 I:1538 P:4449 SKIP:2173 size=56970 bytes
[rawvideo @ 0x61a72571ab80] PACKET SIZE: 2764800, STRIDE: 3840
[libx264 @ 0x61a725754c40] frame= 325 QP=24.00 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:150 I:2553 P:4310 SKIP:1297 size=64782 bytes
pipe:: corrupt input packet in stream 0
[rawvideo @ 0x61a72571ab80] PACKET SIZE: 2751960, STRIDE: 3822
[rawvideo @ 0x61a72571ab80] Invalid buffer size, packet size 2751960 < expected frame_size 2764800
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument
[out_0_0 @ 0x61a72575f400] EOF on sink link out_0_0:default.
[out_0_1 @ 0x61a726577f80] EOF on sink link out_0_1:default.
No more output streams to write to, finishing.
[libx264 @ 0x61a725754c40] frame= 326 QP=24.00 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:152 I:1076 P:4002 SKIP:3082 size=44541 bytes
[libx264 @ 0x61a725754c40] frame= 327 QP=24.00 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:154 I:2493 P:4545 SKIP:1122 size=62617 bytes
[libx264 @ 0x61a725754c40] frame= 328 QP=24.00 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:156 I:1383 P:4328 SKIP:2449 size=50782 bytes
[libx264 @ 0x61a725754c40] frame= 329 QP=24.00 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:158 I:2179 P:4376 SKIP:1605 size=57972 bytes
[libx264 @ 0x61a725754c40] frame= 330 QP=24.00 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:160 I:925  P:3772 SKIP:3463 size=37181 bytes

I tried to give bufsize flags too, but even that wouldnt help.
I'm a total beginner to ffmpeg. I tried to give the correct resolution, tried all pix_fmt from the documentation, and also experimented with different values of fps. But the problem with split screen and audio distortion continues.

you use a subprocess and pipes. some data appears to have disappeared, so now you're no longer in sync as you read frames.

so how do I fix this?? if data loss is happening because of subprocess and pipes, what can I use instead??

Why aren't you connecting the video capture device and the audio file directly to FFmpeg?

Also, you may be sharing the same pipe pipe: for both video and audio, which could be the reason for the corruption. Are you on Windows or non-Windows system?

Because the cv2 frames are being processed somewhere before merging them with the audio.
I'm on Linux
Distributor ID:Ubuntu Description:Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS Release:22.04 Codename:jammy

just use PyAV. don't mess around with subprocesses and pipes.
